# Is strict monotonicity of probability equivalent to "only the empty set has probability zero"?

Tags: probability

I define a probability space to be strictly monotone if, given that $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets, $A$ being a proper subset of $B$ implies that the probability of $A$ is strictly less than the probability of $B$. Is that condition equivalent to "only the empty set has probability zero"? Certainly, one direction of the equivalence is clear to me, but what about the other direction? If it is not equivalent, can someone give a probability space where only the empty set has probability zero, but the probability space is not strictly monotone?

Comment: Which direction is clear to you?

Comment: If $B$ is a non-empty set with $0$ probability then taking $A=\emptyset\subset B$ contradicts strict montonicity.  The only question is how sets without probabilities are treated, and I don't think this is clear.

Comment: Anyways, imagine $B\subset A, B\ne A$. Then $P(A)=P(B)+P(A\setminus B)$ and, to prove that $P(A)>P(B)$ you only need to prove that $P(A\setminus B)>0$. Which is true because $A\setminus B\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: If $C \subsetneq D$ and $P(C)=P(D)$ then $D \backslash C \not =\emptyset$ but $P(D \backslash C)=0$

Comment: @Henry  But $P(C)$ might not exist.  It's not clear (to me) whether the OP is assuming that all these subsets actually have probabilities (nor how that plays into the definition).

Comment: @lulu: it says "probability space" so I would assume all sets or events under discussion are in the sigma algebra and have a probability

Comment: @Henry  So you think that "subset" just considers those elements in the sigma algebra?  Maybe.  But I think the OP should state that explicitly.

Comment: @StinkingBishop : +1 on your first comment. It made me realize that someone could get users to completely solve an if and only if homework question by saying "one direction is clear to me," getting a response for one of the directions, and responding "that was the direction that was clear to me" to elicit an answer for the remaining direction. =)

Comment: If $P$ is strictly monotonic and $P(N)=0$, then $P(X)=P(N)+P(N^c)=P(N^c)$. Therefore, $N^c=X$, which implies $N=\emptyset$. Conversely, if the only measure zero set is $\emptyset$ and $A\subsetneq B$ are measurable, then $P(B)=P(A)+P(B\setminus A)$. Since $B\setminus A\neq \emptyset$, then $P(B\setminus A)>0$. Therefore, $P(B)>P(A)$.

Comment: @user85667 You should put that as an answer.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear that $A$ and $B$ are supposed to be measurable.